# How to merge two rows in android table layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to know How to merge two rows in android table layout. 
I know android:layout_span used to merge columns and whats the attribute used for merging two rows?

Comment: Why don't you use Linear layout with horizontal/vertical orientation. it would fetch you the desire result you are looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6177865/4232337   may help you

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela thx for ur reply but for  my requirement only i'm preferring table layout.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for replying to an old post. This worked for me:

```
<TableLayout>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
        android:text="Single L"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
        <TextView
        android:text="Single R"
        android:layout_column="2"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
        android:text="Double"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Hope someone will find it useful.

P.S.: note that the underlying elements must contain `span` + `weight` or `column` values specified.

Comment: android:layout_span="2" is quite enough

Answer (score 0):

There is no rowspan attribute in `TableLayout`. Better use `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. It's much simpler. Or use `GridLayout` for API Level > 13

If you depend on `TableLayout` you can achieve a rowspan as follows:

```
<TableLayout ...>
    <TableRow..>

        <!-- Column 1 : Rowspan 2 --> 
        <TextView .../>                      

        <!-- Column 2 : 2 Rows -->
        <TableLayout ...>
            <TableRow..>
                <TextView .../>                     
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow..>
                <TextView .../>              
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout> 

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Solution with `LinearLayouts` (cheap & simple):

```
<LinearLayout 
    ...
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- Column 1 -->
    <LinearLayout
        ... 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView .../>  

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Column 2 -->
    <LinearLayout
        ... 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView .../>  
        <TextView .../>  

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: A comment in xml has another syntax: <!-- this is a comment -->